# Angular5 property binding arrays with @Input

Tags: arrays, angular, data-binding

I'm trying to propagate a change from a component to one of its siblings through their parent via an EventEmitter. The change is to the status of a user in an array.

Here's my code:

**child1.component.ts (source)**

```
@Output() adminAdded = new EventEmitter<Array<AdminDetails>>();
...
setAdminStatus(index: number, status: string): void {
  this.admins[index].status = status;
  this.adminAdded.emit(this.admins);
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
onAdminAdded(adminDetails: Array<AdminDetails>): void {
  Object.assign(this.adminDetails, adminDetails]);
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<child1-component (adminAdded)="onAdminAdded($event)"></child1-component>
<child2-component [admins]="adminDetails"></child2-component>
```

**child2.component.ts**

```
adminMails: string[];
@Input() set admins(admins: Array<AdminDetails>) {
    if (!admins) {
        return;
    }
    adminMails = admins.filter(x => x.status === 'Active').map(x => x.email);
}
```

and here I'm displaying the emails of active admins. The issue is that the change only gets as far as the parent component. The breakpoint at `Object.assign` gets hit, but in the setter, it does not.

I assume it is because the reference to the array is the same and it doesn't recognize the change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Angular only detect changes when the reference object changes, but not when its content changes.

You can bypass this by moving your logic inside a [DoCheck](https://angular.io/api/core/DoCheck) lifecycle hook, which is able to detect changes in object properties.

**Edit**

As discussed, If you are worried about DoCheck being called too often, creating an entirely new object and reassigning it to your input property should do the trick, as the reference would be different.

Comment: I read about the DoCheck hook, but it seemed to be called real often. Is there no way to force an update of the input property?

Comment: If you are worried about DoCheck being called too often, creating an entirely new object and reassigning it to your input property should do the trick, as the reference would be different.

Comment: @bugs Could you edit that into the answer, so I can accept?

Comment: @AnandG Thanks, but I don't want to introduce a whole new service and the overhead of using observable just to keep track of an array.

Comment: Edited the answer